# Trying to get property 'Product_image' of non-object (View: F:\softwares\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Tags: laravel-7

I am trying to display products in home.blade.php view. Its gives me error of "Trying to get property 'Product_image' of non-object".
Here is my HomeController Index method

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::pluck('name','id');
        return view('home',[
            'products' => $products,
        ]);
    }
```

and my Home.blade.php is given below

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                @foreach ($products as $product)
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 height" style="font-weight: bold;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$product->Product_image) }}" width="200px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 height">
                            <div class="row" style="font-size: 30px;font-weight: bold">
                                {{ $product->name }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                Description: {{ $product->description }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                Price: {{ $product->price }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                Category: {{ $product->category->name }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                Sub-Category: {{ $product->subcategory->name }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"> Add to Cart</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
```

How I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HomeController Index method I changed Product::pluck('name','id') to Product::all();

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('home',[
            'products' => $products,
        ]);
    }
```